# What are the latest xcode version's are supporting in phonegap2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am working in Phonegap 2.0 cordova in Xcode 4.2 version using Mac OS X Snow Leopard. Now i want switch to Xcode 4.3 and Mac OS Lion. I don't know Phonegap 2.0 will be supportable in XCode 4.3 and Mac OS Lion. Anyone please help tell what the Mac OS and XCode version will be supportable for Phonegap 2.0 Cordova iOS development? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova 2.0 should support with Xcode 4.3 because in PhoneGap official site it has been recommended that the basic requirement for Cordova 2.0 with iOS is Xcode 4.3+.

for more information you can follow these links

[guide for getting started ios](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html)

[improvements in cordova](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/improvements-in-cordova-2-0-0-for-ios/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i am using xcode4.3 also. The phonegap2.0 supporting in xcode4.3. But the phonegap2.0 API'S (like:Camera,file,Contact) these are all not working in xcode4.3. If you have any idea about it. Please lei me know. Thanks in advance.